# Is the order of events when reusing a source observable in a pipeline defined?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable, undefined-behavior, race-condition

## The premise

The following rxjs code is expected to accumulate all events that happens in the same micro-task as a single array (buffer) and then release the buffer for the next micro-task to handle:

```
ob.pipe(buffer(ob.pipe(debounceTime(0)))).subscribe(console.log);

// is expected to log [1,2,3] then [4] 100% of the time.
ob.next(1);
ob.next(2);
setTimeout(() => ob.next(4));
ob.next(3);
```

In theory, this works fine, but I have doubts about this being a guarantied behavior for all kind of sources (new Observable, output of an operator, subjects, etc.).

## The main question

Could timing in the events of `ob` causes some of the events to end up in the wrong (next) buffer?
Could implementation details of `buffer` or `debounceTime` outside of the documented behavior causes the same issue?

In this case, I refer to "the wrong buffer" as slippage, where we would get `[1,2]` then `[3,4]` instead of the expected value due to the order of execution of the two operators.

## Additional exploration

What if ob is defined as `ob = ob.pipe(share())`, making sure that both the `buffer` and `debounceTime` operators gets notified *at the same time*?
What if the buffer time is increased? Is there a risk of slippage if notification arrives too close to the debounce limit?

I have a feeling this will only work in the case where `ob` is published/shared. In that case:
Is this considered idiomatic rx code since the proper behavior of this chain could change depending on other operators around it?
Is there a better way to do this that would avoid those race-conditions? Maybe create my own operator?

To me, it feels very strange to see the same source observable "gating" its own values like this. I could definitely see this code break just because debounceTime observer triggers before buffer's, or the opposite. I guess the question could also apply to cases like `ob.pipe(takeUntil(ob))` or `ob.pipe(bufferWhen(() => ob))`, even though they make little sense at first glance.

Comment: Not helpful for an answer, but why not `bufferTime(0)`?

Comment: O yeah, quite obvious - releases in infinite loop.

Comment: Also, you're code does not work as presented, releasing [1,2,3,4] in the same buffer.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/debounce-time

Comment: Pretty sure it's not guaranteed behavior. JS's event loop standard isn't perfectly implemented by most browsers. Even if it were, it's a sort of fragile construct to rely on. As various web-helpers expand what it means for JS to be multithreaded, code that relies heavily on the event loop's implementation details will likely get hard to maintain.